# How to tabulate a total amount of points that fall within months?

Tags: r, date

I have a df1:

```
ID    Month     Score
716   5/2/2020   30
87    8/1/2020   34
190   5/30/2020  90
18    6/18/2020  100
19    7/2/2020   90
102   8/17/2020  89
60    7/7/2020   99
100   8/6/2020   109
77    9/5/2020   98
88    9/6/2020   99  
99    12/4/2020  55
```

I would like to make a new df2 that calculates the 'event's' within each month. And then I would like to graph these totals on a chart. Such as:

Df2

```
Month       Events
05/2020     2
06/2020     1
07/2020     2
08/2020     2
09/2020     2
10/2020     0
11/2020     0
12/2020     1
```

The graph would have months on the X-axis and events on the y-axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
aggregate(dat$Score,
          list(format(as.Date(dat$Month, format="%m/%d/%Y"), format="%m/%Y")), 
          FUN = length)
#   Group.1 x
# 1 05/2020 2
# 2 06/2020 1
# 3 07/2020 2
# 4 08/2020 3
# 5 09/2020 2
# 6 12/2020 1
```

Comment: Do you know how I could easily put this into a graph?

Comment: That is entirely too vague, there are several ways to visualize this data.

Answer (score 1):

We convert the 'Month' to `Date`, and then to `yearmon` class (from `zoo`) to get the frequency `count`, then use `complete` (from `tidyr`) to expand the rows for those missing months by taking the `seq`uence from `min` to `max` `by` 1 month interval, and reformat the 'Month'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   count(Month = as.Date(as.yearmon(mdy(Month)))) %>%
   complete(Month = seq(min(Month), max(Month), 
         by = '1 month'), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
   mutate(Month = format(Month, '%m/%Y'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#  Month       n
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 05/2020     2
#2 06/2020     1
#3 07/2020     2
#4 08/2020     3
#5 09/2020     2
#6 10/2020     0
#7 11/2020     0
#8 12/2020     1
```

---

If we need to plot, use `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>%
  count(Month = as.Date(as.yearmon(mdy(Month)))) %>%
  complete(Month = seq(min(Month), max(Month), 
      by = '1 month'), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = n)) + 
     geom_col()+ 
     scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = '%m/%Y') + 
     theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(716L, 87L, 190L, 18L, 19L, 102L, 60L, 100L, 
77L, 88L, 99L), Month = c("5/2/2020", "8/1/2020", "5/30/2020", 
"6/18/2020", "7/2/2020", "8/17/2020", "7/7/2020", "8/6/2020", 
"9/5/2020", "9/6/2020", "12/4/2020"), Score = c(30L, 34L, 90L, 
100L, 90L, 89L, 99L, 109L, 98L, 99L, 55L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```